# list of values to array chain

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$a = Array("one", "two", "three");
$b = "text"
```

I have been trying to transform the above array into something like this:

```
$a = Array("one" => Array("two" => Array("three" => "text")));
```

I am looking for a way to do it without improvising but so far no luck and googleing seems to turn up with everything but what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion

```
function make(array $array, $value) {
    $first = array_shift($array);

    if (count($array) === 0) {
        return array($first => $value);
    } else {
        return array($first => make($array, $value);
    }
}
```

It takes the first item of the array and places it in `$first`. When placed in `$first` it is removed from `$array`. Then it checks if the array has some items left. If so it coninues the loop otherwise it end the loop.

Hope it works for you

So you can call it like:

```
$a = Array("one", "two", "three");
$b = "text";

$array = make($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=count($array)-1;
$b=array();
$a=$array[$i];
while($i>0) {
  $b=array($array[$i-1]=>$a);
  $a=$b;
  $i--;
}

var_dump($a);
```